# How to set options for a function in a jQuery like way

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a lot of jQuery functions you are able to pass an options object to the function. Internally that is overriding the default options for the function. I image you can do this in the following way

```
function myFunc (userOptions) {
    userOptions = userOptions || {};

    var defaultOptions = {
        'myOption': true;
    };

    var options = {
        'myOption': userOptions.hasOwnProperty('myOption') ? userOptions.myOptions : defaultOptions.myOption;
    };

    ...

    if (options.myOption) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This is really tedious though and seems error prone especially to maintain. So my question is what is the easiest, safest way to do this?

Comment: I want my functions to accept an options object like jQuery functions often do. I'm asking about the easiest, safest way to override the default options with the user specified options for use inside the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being explicit is not a bad idea because it keeps control and clarity. However, you *could* do something like this:

```
var actualOptions = defaultOptions;
for(var property in userOptions) {
    if(userOptions.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        actualOptions[property] = userOptions[property];
    }
}
```

Note that I said "something like". There is actually a little flaw in the above, namely it will override the defaultOptions object. I'll leave it up to you to avoid that from happening, the loop is the core idea here. Or if you prefer ECMAScript 5

```
var actualOptions = defaultOptions,
    keys = Object.keys(userOptions);
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    actualOptions[keys[i]] = userOptions[keys[i]];
}
```

Since you are already using jQuery, you could utilize jQuery's abilities here and, as Andreas pointed out in the comments, use

```
var actualOptions = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, userOptions);
```

Comment: Or, because of the jQuery tag, `var actualOptions = $.extend(defaultOptions, userOptions)`

Comment: That's probably the better idea to also avoid the problem I just mentioned in my edit, yes.

Comment: I've made a little mistake... The first argument is the target of the extend, so in my example `defaultOptions` would be the merged object (the same as `actualOptions`). If you need to keep `defaultOptions` untouched then you would have to use `var actualOptions = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, userOptions);`

Comment: And I just copied that mistake. ;) I edited my answer as well (and this time I tried it myself before doing so).

Answer (score 0):

jquery uses the `.extend` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method internally to override the default with the user properties.

In your case you would have to do this for all properties manually, instead simply use a loop through the properties and check for each if they exist in the user options and then assign it to your internal options.

something like

```
var options = {myOpt1:1, myOpt2:2};
var userOptions = {myOpt1:3};

for(var p in options){
    if(userOptions.hasOwnProperty(p)){
        options[p] = userOptions[p];
    }
}

console.log(options);
```

or simply use jquery extend which does the same and does it safely, because the above loop is not really safe code.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery I generally see this pattern as a shortcut like so:

```
function myFunc(userOptions) {
    userOptions = userOptions || {};

    var defaultOptions = {
            'opt1': true,
            'opt2': false
        },

        // Preserve defaultOptions object, and deep copy userOptions
        options = $.extend(true, {}, defaultOptions, userOptions);

    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Jquery has an "extend" method which does what you want:
[Jquery extend api reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).
It essentially does the loop through properties for you.

If you don't want to use query, or write your own code, you can use [underscore.js](http://underscore.js).  Writing your own loop as suggested by Ingo Burk is not a bad idea.